# Writing option on one's own default

Tags: option-pricing, cds, replication

Maybe this is a weird question, but suppose that, for some reason, one would like to write an (implicit) option whose payoff is indexed on the writer's CDS spread.
I would like to know what would be a "fair" premium to charge for this option, knowing that there's no concrete hedging strategy available to the writer (which would require selling protection against its own default) ?
Of course the term "fair" is quite vague and is actually part of my question.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: sounds like [wrong way risk](http://www.risk.net/risk-management/credit-risk/1557468/wrong-way-risk).

Comment: Expanding on that; the price for this option is only what your counterparrty is willing to pay. Unlikely to be much above zero unless the option receivable is high up in capital structure.

Comment: EDIT: you could make it a digital default option that delivers value either in form of super senior bonds or from a specifically created ringfenced SPV